# browser.inputbox() not working with onedit triggerT

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is a code for `browser.msgbox` if a specific value is entered in a cell. We want to take an input value for every such entry & store values. The `onEdit` Trigger is crucial for this function. The onEdit works with msgBox but not with inputBox. what should be changed so that inputBox pops up for onEdit.

```
function onEdit(e){

    enter code here`var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    enter code here`var ss = ws.getActiveSheet()
    var sheetName = "Sheet1"
    if(ss.getName() == sheetName){
    var activeCell = ws.getActiveCell()
    var cellValue = activeCell.getValue()
    var row = activeCell.getRow()
    var col = activeCell.getColumn()
    var colCheck = 6
    if(col == colCheck){
      if(cellValue == "nok"){
        if(ss.getRange(row-1, colCheck).getValue() == "nok" && ss.getRange(row-1, colCheck+1).isBlank()){
          Browser.msgBox("Commment Please ") //I WANT AN INPUT BOX HERE
      }else{
          Browser.msgBox("Commment Please ") ////I WANT AN INPUT BOX HERE
          activeCell.setBackground("red")
      }
}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### `Browser.inputBox` does not work with a [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) `onEdit` trigger.

You need to replace it with an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) one.

For this,

- Rename your function
- Go from the Apps Script Editor UI to `Edit->Current Project's triggers`
- Click on `+ Add trigger`
- Chose your function as the `function to run`
- Chose `On edit` as `event type`

[image]

Comment: The onEdit works with msgBox but not with inputBox. what should be changed so that inputBox pops up for onEdit.

Comment: change the simple `onEdit` trigger to an installable `onEdit` trigger.